# How can I compile Programmer Dvorak?

Tags: c, open-source, linker, driver, wdk

I'm trying to compile the open source project [Programmer Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/). The problem is that it's a bit old and doesn't build with the current versions of the build tools.

You can see the full source code with modifications I made online at my [project's Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/). [Revision 2](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/browse/?r=2#svn/trunk) is the unmodified source files from the original project. [Revision 3](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/browse/?r=3#svn/trunk) is where I made all the significant changes. You can see a [diff between the two revisions here](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/detail?r=3).

The only obvious problems that are left are a few LINK warnings:

- [LNK4254](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235500(VS.80).aspx) (e.g. `section '.edata' (40000040) merged into '.data' (C0000040) with different attributes.`) -- I asked a stand-alone version of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383675/how-can-i-resolve-lnk4254-warnings-in-link-exe).
- [LNK4210](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/708by912(VS.71).aspx) (e.g. `.CRT section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators`)

How do I fix these warnings? <strike>Can I ignore them?</strike>

Despite these warnings, it still produces an exe. If I go ahead and run it, though, it doesn't get installed correctly and I need to resort to a system restore in order to install the official version again.

This might be because of the warnings or simply because I didn't modify the project correctly.

What else do I need to do to make this project installable?

---

### The build process (and an explanation of my modifications):

It says that you need the Windows DDK, but it seems like the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=36a2630f-5d56-43b5-b996-7633f2ec14ff) has replaced it, so I got that instead. I only installed the "Build Environments".

#### 1. According to [`Readme.txt`](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/browse/trunk/README.txt), you are supposed to run:

```
build-layout && build-installer
```

#### 2. [`build-layout.bat`](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/browse/trunk/build-layout.bat) is run.

I had to modify this file ([see the diff here](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/diff?spec=svn5&r=3&format=side&path=/trunk/build-layout.bat&old_path=/trunk/build-layout.bat&old=2)):

- `WinDDK` path was modified since I have a newer version <sup>(MOD-1)</sup>.
- `set PATH=` ... `%WINDDK%\bin\x86\x86;` was added since `link.exe` is located there <sup>(MOD-2)</sup>.
- In `set INCLUDE=`, `%WINDDK%\inc\wxp` was changed to `%WINDDK%\inc\api`, because the `wxp` folder does not exist, and my best guess is that the `api` folder was needed since it contains `kbd.h`, which [`kbddvp.c`](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/browse/trunk/kbddvp.c) uses <sup>(MOD-3)</sup>.
- For `set LIB=`, `%WINDDK%\lib\crt` was modified to `%WINDDK%\lib\crt\i386`, so that `libcmt.lib` could be found. See MOD-7 below. <sup>(MOD-4)</sup>

#### 3. [`fkbddvp.mak`](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/browse/trunk/kbddvp.mak) is run.

I had to modify this file ([see the diff here](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/diff?spec=svn6&old=2&r=6&format=side&path=/trunk/kbddvp.mak#)):

- The path for the variable `CL32` was changed from `$(WINDDK)\bin\x86\cl.exe` to `$(WINDDK)\bin\x86\x86\cl.exe`, the first .exe doesn't exist, I believe this is the .exe I'm supposed to use instead. <sup>(MOD-5)</sup>
- The path for the variable `CL64` was changed from `$(WINDDK)\bin\win64\x86\amd64\cl.exe` to `$(WINDDK)\bin\x86\amd64\cl.exe`, this is my best guess as to where the missing .exe is. <sup>(MOD-6)</sup>
- `-opt:nowin98` removed to suppress warning [LNK4224](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7ys78k4.aspx) (i.e. `/OPT:NOWIN98 is no longer supported`), as [suggested by Bobby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360746/how-can-i-compile-programmer-dvorak#comment-3552068). <sup>(MOD-10)</sup>
- Instead of using the non-existent `libc.lib`, I'm using `libcmt.lib`. I read [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/45a46d37-5e20-4e1a-87e7-9f9f65986f6a/) which recommends using this file instead. <sup>(MOD-7)</sup>
- Instead of using the obsolete utility `cabarc`, I'm using `makecab` with [`makecab-dir.ddf`](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/browse/trunk/makecab-dir.ddf). I took [my best guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375908/how-do-i-convert-a-multi-file-cabarc-command-to-a-corresponding-makecab-command) as to how to execute the same logic with this new utility. <sup>(MOD-8)</sup>

#### 4. [`build-installer.bat`](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/browse/trunk/build-installer.bat) is run.

I had to modify this file ([see the diff here](http://code.google.com/p/ergo-dvorak-for-developers/source/diff?spec=svn5&r=3&format=side&path=/trunk/build-installer.bat&old_path=/trunk/build-installer.bat&old=2)):

- This was also using `cabarc` and I modified it to use `makcab`, similar to MOD-8, except that here it creates the .ddf file programmaticaly. <sup>(MOD-9)</sup>

---

### The complete output

Here's the complete output, if you want to see it:

```
>build-layout && build-installer
        "C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\x86\x86\cl.exe" -nologo -c -I..\inc -Zp8 -Gy
 -W3 -WX -Gz -Gm- -EHs-c- -GR- -GF -Zl -Oxs  -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -Fokbddvp32.o
bj kbddvp.c
kbddvp.c
        rc kbddvp.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6908.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        link -machine:ix86 -nologo -dll -base:0x5FFF0000 -subsystem:native -def:
kbddvp.def -noentry  -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data
-merge:.bss=.data  -ignore:4078,4070 -section:.data,re -stack:0x40000,0x1000 -op
t:ref,icf  -release -out:kbddvp32.dll kbddvp32.obj kbddvp.res
   Creating library kbddvp32.lib and object kbddvp32.exp
LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.edata' (40000040) merged into '.data' (C000004
0) with different attributes
LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.rdata' (40000040) merged into '.data' (C000004
0) with different attributes
LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.text' (60000020) merged into '.data' (C0000040
) with different attributes
LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.bss' (C0000080) merged into '.data' (C0000040)
 with different attributes
        "C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\x86\amd64\cl.exe" -nologo -c -I..\inc -Zp8 -
Gy -W3 -WX -Gz -Gm- -EHs-c- -GR- -GF -Zl -Oxs  -DBUILD_WOW6432 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x
0501 -Fokbddvp64.obj kbddvp.c
kbddvp.c
        link -machine:amd64 -nologo -dll -base:0x5FFE0000 -subsystem:native -def
:kbddvp.def -noentry  -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data
 -merge:.bss=.data  -ignore:4078,4070 -section:.data,re -stack:0x40000,0x1000 -o
pt:ref,icf  -release -out:kbddvp64.dll kbddvp64.obj kbddvp.res
   Creating library kbddvp64.lib and object kbddvp64.exp
LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.edata' (40000040) merged into '.data' (C000004
0) with different attributes
LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.rdata' (40000040) merged into '.data' (C000004
0) with different attributes
LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.text' (60000020) merged into '.data' (C0000040
) with different attributes
LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.bss' (C0000080) merged into '.data' (C0000040)
 with different attributes
        "C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\x86\x86\cl.exe" -nologo -c -Folauncher.obj l
auncher.c
launcher.c
        link -machine:ix86 -nologo -subsystem:windows -release -nodefaultlib -ou
t:launcher.exe  launcher.obj kernel32.lib libcmt.lib user32.lib shell32.lib
libcmt.lib(cpu_disp.obj) : warning LNK4210: .CRT section exists; there may be un
handled static initializers or terminators
        makecab /F makecab-dir.ddf
Microsoft (R) Cabinet Maker - Version 5.1.2600.5512
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved..

27,686 bytes in 4 files
Total files:              4
Bytes before:        27,686
Bytes after:          8,140
After/Before:            29.40% compression
Time:                     0.19 seconds ( 0 hr  0 min  0.19 sec)
Throughput:             144.58 Kb/second
        iexpress /N /Q /M kbddvp.sed
        1 file(s) copied.
Microsoft (R) Cabinet Maker - Version 5.1.2600.5512
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved..

60,290 bytes in 16 files
Total files:             16
Bytes before:        60,290
Bytes after:         16,876
After/Before:            27.99% compression
Time:                     0.27 seconds ( 0 hr  0 min  0.27 sec)
Throughput:             221.34 Kb/second
```

Comment: You can safely remove the nowin98-flag from the script. This has become the default behavior of 2008+ compilers.

Comment: Also at line 27 and 34 of `kbddvp.mak` are the merge-options which are triggering the second warning. One try worth would be to simply remove them, too. However, just guessing.

Comment: At the lines 26 and 33 are the flags `-noentry` which might issue linker warning No. 3.

Answer (score 1):

AMD64? I think that is the issue there.

Perhaps the problem is just a matter of you using BOTH the files for 32 or 64 ISA at the same time.

Like:

kbddvp32.dll
kbddvp64.dll

Try using the ones for your platform ISA and take out the rest.

Comment: 64-bit Windows needs both; one for native 64-bit applications and one for 32-bit applications that run in WoW64.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235500(VS.80).aspx -- LNK4254
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/708by912(VS.71).aspx -- LNK4210

Note: LNK4210 can be caused by -NOENTRY but only your code can tell is using it is right or wrong
LNK4254 is most probalby a "poltical" warning (a section declared as "read only" in a new version of some lib)

And I assume that you are running 2 completely clean and separated builds for x86 and x64. If not, you have to do that no matter what and do it first. So called mixed builds result in all kids of random-looking failures and there's noting to fix there - just have to build separately.

Comment: There is no mixed builds; see comment @Rui.

Answer (score 1):

I've merged sections before (had to, for what we were doing). It can get tricky, and I think one of the problems we had has bitten you too: you're merging the `.text` section (which contains executable code) into the `.data` section (which doesn't). The `.data` section doesn't get the executable bit, and the /SECTION linker option (which should be able to force it to be executable) apparently doesn't work on `.data`.

The way we worked around it is to create a new section, then merge all of the others into it. Here's how:

In one of your *.cpp files, add the following lines after your #include lines:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.merged,ERW")
#pragma code_seg(".merged")
```

(The second line has to be above some actual code, to create the new section.)

Then change the `-merge:` commands to go to a new `.merged` section instead of the `.data` section...

```
-merge:.edata=.merged -merge:.rdata=.merged -merge:.text=.merged -merge:.bss=.merged
```

...and add a new one to put the `.data` section there too:

```
-merge:.data=.merged
```

That should do the trick. You'll still get some warnings about the sections having different attributes, but you should be able to ignore them now (we suppress them by using `/ignore:4254` on the linker). The final `.merged` section will have executable, read, and write permissions, which will eliminate the problem.

(Our code is compiled with MSVC2005, but this should work in later ones too.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that the source of where all these command line parameters came from is http://levicki.net/articles/tips/2006/09/29/HOWTO_Build_keyboard_layouts_for_Windows_x64.php. The reason it was used was that KLC 1.3 did not support 64 bit operating systems. KLC 1.4, added support for 64 bit operating systems. That means that if you can get away with creating a layout using KLC that supports all of the features you want, you should use that instead.

If, however, you need more advanced features and would like to compile these files yourself, you need to find out the new utilities and parameters that are used for KLC 1.4. The ones you have listed are outdated and meant for KLC 1.3.

I used Process Monitor to figure out which utilities are run, and what command line parameters are sent to them. Here they are, in the order they are run:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4\bin\i386\kbdutool.exe" -n -x -u ..\.\tmpYourKeyboard.txt
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\cl.exe -nologo -IC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DNOGDICAPMASKS -DNOWINMESSAGES -DNOWINSTYLES -DNOSYSMETRICS -DNOMENUS -DNOICONS -DNOSYSCOMMANDS -DNORASTEROPS -DNOSHOWWINDOW -DOEMRESOURCE -DNOATOM -DNOCLIPBOARD -DNOCOLOR -DNOCTLMGR -DNODRAWTEXT -DNOGDI -DNOKERNEL -DNONLS -DNOMB -DNOMEMMGR -DNOMETAFILE -DNOMINMAX -DNOMSG -DNOOPENFILE -DNOSCROLL -DNOSERVICE -DNOSOUND -DNOTEXTMETRIC -DNOWINOFFSETS -DNOWH -DNOCOMM -DNOKANJI -DNOHELP -DNOPROFILER -DNODEFERWINDOWPOS -DNOMCX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DRoster -DSTD_CALL -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 /MD /c /Zp8 /Gy /W3 /WX /Gz /Gm- /EHs-c- /GR- /GF -Z7 /Oxs   YourKeyboard.c
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\cl.exe -nologo -IC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DNOGDICAPMASKS -DNOWINMESSAGES -DNOWINSTYLES -DNOSYSMETRICS -DNOMENUS -DNOICONS -DNOSYSCOMMANDS -DNORASTEROPS -DNOSHOWWINDOW -DOEMRESOURCE -DNOATOM -DNOCLIPBOARD -DNOCOLOR -DNOCTLMGR -DNODRAWTEXT -DNOGDI -DNOKERNEL -DNONLS -DNOMB -DNOMEMMGR -DNOMETAFILE -DNOMINMAX -DNOMSG -DNOOPENFILE -DNOSCROLL -DNOSERVICE -DNOSOUND -DNOTEXTMETRIC -DNOWINOFFSETS -DNOWH -DNOCOMM -DNOKANJI -DNOHELP -DNOPROFILER -DNODEFERWINDOWPOS -DNOMCX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DRoster -DSTD_CALL -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 /MD /c /Zp8 /Gy /W3 /WX /Gz /Gm- /EHs-c- /GR- /GF -Z7 /Oxs   YourKeyboard.c
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\rc.exe -r -iC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DSTD_CALL -DCONDITION_HANDLING=1 -DNT_UP=1 -DNT_INST=0 -DWIN32=100 -D_NT1X_=100 -DWINNT=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0400 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DDEVL=1 -DFPO=1 -DNDEBUG -l 409 YourKeyboard.rc
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\rc.exe -r -iC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DSTD_CALL -DCONDITION_HANDLING=1 -DNT_UP=1 -DNT_INST=0 -DWIN32=100 -D_NT1X_=100 -DWINNT=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0400 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DDEVL=1 -DFPO=1 -DNDEBUG -l 409 YourKeyboard.rc
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\link.exe -nologo -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re -MERGE:_PAGE=PAGE -MERGE:_TEXT=.text -MACHINE:IX86 -SECTION:INIT,d -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF -IGNORE:4039,4078 -noentry -dll -libpath:C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\lib\i386 -subsystem:native,5.0 -merge:.rdata=.text -PDBPATH:NONE -STACK:0x40000,0x1000 /opt:nowin98 -osversion:4.0 -version:4.0 /release -def:YourKeyboard.def YourKeyboard.res YourKeyboard.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\link.exe -nologo -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re -MERGE:_PAGE=PAGE -MERGE:_TEXT=.text -MACHINE:IX86 -SECTION:INIT,d -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF -IGNORE:4039,4078 -noentry -dll -libpath:C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\lib\i386 -subsystem:native,5.0 -merge:.rdata=.text -PDBPATH:NONE -STACK:0x40000,0x1000 /opt:nowin98 -osversion:4.0 -version:4.0 /release -def:YourKeyboard.def YourKeyboard.res YourKeyboard.obj
cvtres /machine:x86 /nologo /out:"C:\DOCUME~1\User\LOCALS~1\Temp\lnk1F.tmp" /readonly "YourKeyboard.res"
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4\bin\i386\kbdutool.exe" -n -i -u ..\.\tmpYourKeyboard.txt
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\IA64\cl.exe -nologo -IC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DNOGDICAPMASKS -DNOWINMESSAGES -DNOWINSTYLES -DNOSYSMETRICS -DNOMENUS -DNOICONS -DNOSYSCOMMANDS -DNORASTEROPS -DNOSHOWWINDOW -DOEMRESOURCE -DNOATOM -DNOCLIPBOARD -DNOCOLOR -DNOCTLMGR -DNODRAWTEXT -DNOGDI -DNOKERNEL -DNONLS -DNOMB -DNOMEMMGR -DNOMETAFILE -DNOMINMAX -DNOMSG -DNOOPENFILE -DNOSCROLL -DNOSERVICE -DNOSOUND -DNOTEXTMETRIC -DNOWINOFFSETS -DNOWH -DNOCOMM -DNOKANJI -DNOHELP -DNOPROFILER -DNODEFERWINDOWPOS -DNOMCX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DRoster -DSTD_CALL -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 /MD /c /Zp8 /Gy /W3 /WX /Gz /Gm- /EHs-c- /GR- /GF -Z7 /Oxs   YourKeyboard.c
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\IA64\cl.exe -nologo -IC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DNOGDICAPMASKS -DNOWINMESSAGES -DNOWINSTYLES -DNOSYSMETRICS -DNOMENUS -DNOICONS -DNOSYSCOMMANDS -DNORASTEROPS -DNOSHOWWINDOW -DOEMRESOURCE -DNOATOM -DNOCLIPBOARD -DNOCOLOR -DNOCTLMGR -DNODRAWTEXT -DNOGDI -DNOKERNEL -DNONLS -DNOMB -DNOMEMMGR -DNOMETAFILE -DNOMINMAX -DNOMSG -DNOOPENFILE -DNOSCROLL -DNOSERVICE -DNOSOUND -DNOTEXTMETRIC -DNOWINOFFSETS -DNOWH -DNOCOMM -DNOKANJI -DNOHELP -DNOPROFILER -DNODEFERWINDOWPOS -DNOMCX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DRoster -DSTD_CALL -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 /MD /c /Zp8 /Gy /W3 /WX /Gz /Gm- /EHs-c- /GR- /GF -Z7 /Oxs   YourKeyboard.c
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\rc.exe -r -iC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DSTD_CALL -DCONDITION_HANDLING=1 -DNT_UP=1 -DNT_INST=0 -DWIN32=100 -D_NT1X_=100 -DWINNT=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0400 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DDEVL=1 -DFPO=1 -DNDEBUG -l 409 YourKeyboard.rc
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\rc.exe -r -iC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DSTD_CALL -DCONDITION_HANDLING=1 -DNT_UP=1 -DNT_INST=0 -DWIN32=100 -D_NT1X_=100 -DWINNT=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0400 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DDEVL=1 -DFPO=1 -DNDEBUG -l 409 YourKeyboard.rc
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\link.exe -nologo -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.srdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re -MERGE:_PAGE=PAGE -MERGE:_TEXT=.text /MACHINE:IA64 -SECTION:INIT,d -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF -IGNORE:4039,4078 -noentry -dll -libpath:C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\lib\ia64 -subsystem:native,5.0 -merge:.rdata=.text -PDBPATH:NONE -STACK:0x40000,0x1000 /opt:nowin98 -osversion:4.0 -version:4.0 /release -def:YourKeyboard.def YourKeyboard.res YourKeyboard.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\link.exe -nologo -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.srdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re -MERGE:_PAGE=PAGE -MERGE:_TEXT=.text /MACHINE:IA64 -SECTION:INIT,d -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF -IGNORE:4039,4078 -noentry -dll -libpath:C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\lib\ia64 -subsystem:native,5.0 -merge:.rdata=.text -PDBPATH:NONE -STACK:0x40000,0x1000 /opt:nowin98 -osversion:4.0 -version:4.0 /release -def:YourKeyboard.def YourKeyboard.res YourKeyboard.obj
cvtres /machine:ia64 /nologo /out:"C:\DOCUME~1\User\LOCALS~1\Temp\lnk20.tmp" /readonly "YourKeyboard.res"
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4\bin\i386\kbdutool.exe" -n -m -u ..\.\tmpYourKeyboard.txt
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\amd64\cl.exe -nologo -IC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DNOGDICAPMASKS -DNOWINMESSAGES -DNOWINSTYLES -DNOSYSMETRICS -DNOMENUS -DNOICONS -DNOSYSCOMMANDS -DNORASTEROPS -DNOSHOWWINDOW -DOEMRESOURCE -DNOATOM -DNOCLIPBOARD -DNOCOLOR -DNOCTLMGR -DNODRAWTEXT -DNOGDI -DNOKERNEL -DNONLS -DNOMB -DNOMEMMGR -DNOMETAFILE -DNOMINMAX -DNOMSG -DNOOPENFILE -DNOSCROLL -DNOSERVICE -DNOSOUND -DNOTEXTMETRIC -DNOWINOFFSETS -DNOWH -DNOCOMM -DNOKANJI -DNOHELP -DNOPROFILER -DNODEFERWINDOWPOS -DNOMCX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DRoster -DSTD_CALL -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 /MD /c /Zp8 /Gy /W3 /WX /Gz /Gm- /EHs-c- /GR- /GF -Z7 /Oxs   YourKeyboard.c
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\amd64\cl.exe -nologo -IC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DNOGDICAPMASKS -DNOWINMESSAGES -DNOWINSTYLES -DNOSYSMETRICS -DNOMENUS -DNOICONS -DNOSYSCOMMANDS -DNORASTEROPS -DNOSHOWWINDOW -DOEMRESOURCE -DNOATOM -DNOCLIPBOARD -DNOCOLOR -DNOCTLMGR -DNODRAWTEXT -DNOGDI -DNOKERNEL -DNONLS -DNOMB -DNOMEMMGR -DNOMETAFILE -DNOMINMAX -DNOMSG -DNOOPENFILE -DNOSCROLL -DNOSERVICE -DNOSOUND -DNOTEXTMETRIC -DNOWINOFFSETS -DNOWH -DNOCOMM -DNOKANJI -DNOHELP -DNOPROFILER -DNODEFERWINDOWPOS -DNOMCX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DRoster -DSTD_CALL -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 /MD /c /Zp8 /Gy /W3 /WX /Gz /Gm- /EHs-c- /GR- /GF -Z7 /Oxs   YourKeyboard.c
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\rc.exe -r -iC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DSTD_CALL -DCONDITION_HANDLING=1 -DNT_UP=1 -DNT_INST=0 -DWIN32=100 -D_NT1X_=100 -DWINNT=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0400 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DDEVL=1 -DFPO=1 -DNDEBUG -l 409 YourKeyboard.rc
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\rc.exe -r -iC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DSTD_CALL -DCONDITION_HANDLING=1 -DNT_UP=1 -DNT_INST=0 -DWIN32=100 -D_NT1X_=100 -DWINNT=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0400 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DDEVL=1 -DFPO=1 -DNDEBUG -l 409 YourKeyboard.rc
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\link.exe -nologo -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re -MERGE:_PAGE=PAGE -MERGE:_TEXT=.text -MACHINE:AMD64 -SECTION:INIT,d -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF -IGNORE:4039,4078 -noentry -dll -libpath:C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\lib\amd64 -subsystem:native,5.0 -merge:.rdata=.text -PDBPATH:NONE -STACK:0x40000,0x1000 /opt:nowin98 -osversion:4.0 -version:4.0 /release -def:YourKeyboard.def YourKeyboard.res YourKeyboard.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\link.exe -nologo -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re -MERGE:_PAGE=PAGE -MERGE:_TEXT=.text -MACHINE:AMD64 -SECTION:INIT,d -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF -IGNORE:4039,4078 -noentry -dll -libpath:C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\lib\amd64 -subsystem:native,5.0 -merge:.rdata=.text -PDBPATH:NONE -STACK:0x40000,0x1000 /opt:nowin98 -osversion:4.0 -version:4.0 /release -def:YourKeyboard.def YourKeyboard.res YourKeyboard.obj
cvtres /machine:amd64 /nologo /out:"C:\DOCUME~1\User\LOCALS~1\Temp\lnk21.tmp" /readonly "YourKeyboard.res"
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4\bin\i386\kbdutool.exe" -n -o -u ..\.\tmpYourKeyboard.txt
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\cl.exe -nologo -IC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DNOGDICAPMASKS -DNOWINMESSAGES -DNOWINSTYLES -DNOSYSMETRICS -DNOMENUS -DNOICONS -DNOSYSCOMMANDS -DNORASTEROPS -DNOSHOWWINDOW -DOEMRESOURCE -DNOATOM -DNOCLIPBOARD -DNOCOLOR -DNOCTLMGR -DNODRAWTEXT -DNOGDI -DNOKERNEL -DNONLS -DNOMB -DNOMEMMGR -DNOMETAFILE -DNOMINMAX -DNOMSG -DNOOPENFILE -DNOSCROLL -DNOSERVICE -DNOSOUND -DNOTEXTMETRIC -DNOWINOFFSETS -DNOWH -DNOCOMM -DNOKANJI -DNOHELP -DNOPROFILER -DNODEFERWINDOWPOS -DNOMCX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DRoster -DSTD_CALL -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 /MD /c /Zp8 /Gy /W3 /WX /Gz /Gm- /EHs-c- /GR- /GF -Z7 /Oxs -DBUILD_WOW6432 -D_WOW6432_ YourKeyboard.c
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\cl.exe -nologo -IC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DNOGDICAPMASKS -DNOWINMESSAGES -DNOWINSTYLES -DNOSYSMETRICS -DNOMENUS -DNOICONS -DNOSYSCOMMANDS -DNORASTEROPS -DNOSHOWWINDOW -DOEMRESOURCE -DNOATOM -DNOCLIPBOARD -DNOCOLOR -DNOCTLMGR -DNODRAWTEXT -DNOGDI -DNOKERNEL -DNONLS -DNOMB -DNOMEMMGR -DNOMETAFILE -DNOMINMAX -DNOMSG -DNOOPENFILE -DNOSCROLL -DNOSERVICE -DNOSOUND -DNOTEXTMETRIC -DNOWINOFFSETS -DNOWH -DNOCOMM -DNOKANJI -DNOHELP -DNOPROFILER -DNODEFERWINDOWPOS -DNOMCX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DRoster -DSTD_CALL -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 /MD /c /Zp8 /Gy /W3 /WX /Gz /Gm- /EHs-c- /GR- /GF -Z7 /Oxs -DBUILD_WOW6432 -D_WOW6432_ YourKeyboard.c
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\rc.exe -r -iC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DSTD_CALL -DCONDITION_HANDLING=1 -DNT_UP=1 -DNT_INST=0 -DWIN32=100 -D_NT1X_=100 -DWINNT=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0400 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DDEVL=1 -DFPO=1 -DNDEBUG -l 409 YourKeyboard.rc
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\rc.exe -r -iC:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\inc -DSTD_CALL -DCONDITION_HANDLING=1 -DNT_UP=1 -DNT_INST=0 -DWIN32=100 -D_NT1X_=100 -DWINNT=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 /DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0400 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DDEVL=1 -DFPO=1 -DNDEBUG -l 409 YourKeyboard.rc
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\link.exe -nologo -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re -MERGE:_PAGE=PAGE -MERGE:_TEXT=.text -MACHINE:IX86 -SECTION:INIT,d -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF -IGNORE:4039,4078 -noentry -dll -libpath:C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\lib\i386 -subsystem:native,5.0 -merge:.rdata=.text -PDBPATH:NONE -STACK:0x40000,0x1000 /opt:nowin98 -osversion:4.0 -version:4.0 /release -def:YourKeyboard.def YourKeyboard.res YourKeyboard.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\bin\i386\link.exe -nologo -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re -MERGE:_PAGE=PAGE -MERGE:_TEXT=.text -MACHINE:IX86 -SECTION:INIT,d -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF -IGNORE:4039,4078 -noentry -dll -libpath:C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.4\lib\i386 -subsystem:native,5.0 -merge:.rdata=.text -PDBPATH:NONE -STACK:0x40000,0x1000 /opt:nowin98 -osversion:4.0 -version:4.0 /release -def:YourKeyboard.def YourKeyboard.res YourKeyboard.obj
cvtres /machine:x86 /nologo /out:"C:\DOCUME~1\User\LOCALS~1\Temp\lnk22.tmp" /readonly "YourKeyboard.res"
```

Comment: Since I don't have time to debug this issue right now, I just decided to create a layout using KLC 1.4, for now. I'll probably try to use process monitor when I do get the time to work on this.

Comment: You don't need the KLC to compile a keyboard driver; the command-line are for the standard linker.

Answer (score 1):

The linked source code is missing the sources.inc file which makes it difficult to get this built with a recent version of the WDK.  The included .bat files are quite useless, they can only work on the author's machine.  I got a clean build using the following steps with WDK version 6001.18002:

- unzip the .cab file to c:\temp\dvorak
- navigate to WDK's src\input\layout folder
- copy the sources.inc file to c:\temp
- edit kbddvp.c and comment the #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN directive
- Start + All Programs, Windows Driver Kits, WDK xxx.xxx, Build Environments, Windows Vista, blabla x86 free.  Pick your own here.
- cd c:\temp\dvorak
- nmake

Doesn't take long, clean build.  No actual test, being equipped with two left hands.

---

The sources.inc file you need:

```
INCLUDES=..\..\inc

C_DEFINES=
UMTYPE=nt
UMBASE=0x1000000
TARGETLIBS=
DLLDEF=$(TARGETNAME).def

!if $(IA64)
SECTION_ALIGNMENT=0x4000
!endif
LINKER_FLAGS = -merge:.edata=.data -merge:.rdata=.data -merge:.text=.data -merge:.bss=.data -section:.data,re

LINKER_FLAGS= $(LINKER_FLAGS) /ignore:4254
NO_RDATA_MERGE=1

TARGETTYPE=DYNLINK
USE_NOLIBS=1
BUFFER_OVERFLOW_CHECKS=0

SOURCES=$(TARGETNAME).c $(TARGETNAME).rc
```

Comment: I have the latest version of the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/WDK/default.mspx), 7600.16385.1, and I don't see the `src\input` folder.

Comment: Well, that's depressing.  I didn't install that version more than a year ago, give or take.  Maybe part of the problem you are having. The sample source code is part and partial of the actual documentation in the WDK.  Has been for two dozen years, this stuff isn't documented, it is shown.  Search your disk for "kbdus.c", the source code for the USA keyboard layout.  When found, navigate to the parent directory to find sources.inc.  When not found, you prolly need to wonder exactly what went wrong when you installed the WDK...

Comment: I just searched the hard drive and tried a reinstall. Unfortunately, I couldn't find that file, so I can't test this method out. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Bizarre.  I updated my answer with the content of sources.inc

Comment: src\input\layout is part of the keyboard driver samples. If you want to compile the layout with the DDK, then you should copy the kbddvp directory under the layout directory and run `build -cZ` from there.

Comment: The batch file will necessarily have to be edited to the paths on the system in question, given that the anemic Windows command line tools does not allow you to even query the Registry without the support tools already in path. The paths in the batch file applies if you selected the defaults when installing.

Answer (score 1):

`launcher` is a program to start an elevated installation of the .inf file,
disabling redirection so that the true `%SystemRoot%` directory is revealed
to a 32-bit process even if it is running in Wow64.

The only routine from the C runtime which it uses is `ZeroMemory`, which is
a macro expanding to `_memset`. In earlier versions, there was no problems
in linking this one routine statically, ignoring the runtime initialization.
Perhaps it is in later versions, which triggers the LNK4210 warning.

You can replace the calls to `ZeroMemory` with this function:

```
void ZeroFill(IN VOID UNALIGNED *ptr, IN SIZE_T len) {
    char *dst;
    for( dst = (char*) ptr; len > 0; len--, dst++) {
        *dst = 0;
    }
}
```

and remove the reference to `libc`/`libcmt` and the directory `%WINDDK%\lib\crt\i386`.

Note also that if you as an Administrator choose Install from the context-menu
in Explorer for the `kbddvp.inf` file, you should be able to do the setup
without the `launcher` program, thus eliminating any errors from that stage. It
is only present for easier redistribution and is not vital.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.2.6 the layout can also be built using the Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition Update 4, on a Windows 7 64-bits machine.