# Compiling Microsoft Keyboard Layout Samples

Tags: windows, wdk, keyboard-layout

I'd like to build a keyboard layout that runs on Win7 and later without using MSKLC.

I downloaded the [Keyboard Layout Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Keyboard-Layout-Sample-b142d9e3), and although it says it requires VS2013 Preview and WDK8.1 Preview, it builds using VS2012 and WDK8 after changing the "Platform Toolset" property from "WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1" to "WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.0".

But: Checking the `kbdus.dll` built with Dependency Viewer reveals that it imports quite a lot of stuff from `kernel32.dll`and from `msvcr110.dll`. This is in contrast to `kbdus.dll` from the `Windows\system32` directory, which, as one might expect, does not import anything and exports one single function.

My first question: Is it an issues that the dll built imports from `msvcr110.dll`?

I guess it is, as Win7 does not include this dll. (Honestly, I'm wondering how this can be, because these are official Microsoft samples.)

Tweaking around with compiler and linker settings, I managed to get rid of imports from `msvcr110.dll`, but the dll built still imports a lot of stuff and is quite large (> 70kB), compared to the original `kbdus.dll` (7kB). It's the same with x86 and x64, Debug and Release builds. I'm looking for the `/compileandlinkanddonothingfancy` switch.

My second question: How can these dlls be built correctly?

(Note: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360746/how-can-i-compile-programmer-dvorak), but it is about WDK7. That will be what I try next, if I don't get it with WDK8.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one should pass `/noentry` to the linker.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this fix. Thanks!